# How to make PDO query work inside a function

Tags: php, pdo

I am try to make an PDO sql inside function but it doesn't work. got no response from it. it works when not using function. my purpose is to make my code small. anyone can shed a light. thanks.

```
function Test() {

    $get_name = $smt->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id = '1'");
    $get_name->execute();

    foreach ($get_name as $temp) {
        $name = $temp['name'];
        $address = $temp['address'];
        $phone = $temp['phone'];
        $page = $temp['page'];
    }

    eval("\$page = \"$page\";");
    echo $page;

    eval("\$page = \"$page\";");
    echo $page;

}

Test();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd probably refactor your code to something like:

```
function getCustomerInfo(PDO $pdo, $customerId) 
{
    // use a prepared statement that can get you info on any customer
    $statement = $pdo->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id = :customerId LIMIT 1");
    // get the result resource from the database
    $result = $statement->execute(array(
        ':customerId' => $customerId
    ));
    // fetch the first row in the result as an associative array
    // and return it to the caller.
    return $result->fetchFirst(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

// use your connection in place of $pdo
$customerData = getCustomerInfo($pdo, 1);

// now you can do stuff with your data
var_dump($customerData);
```

This is better because it does not rely on global state, functions should never-ever-ever do that. and it uses prepared, parameterized sql that makes it faster and the function more useful for customers other that the one where id=1.

Answer (score 6):

You need to make the pdo instance global within the function

```
function Test() {

    global $smt;
```

Comment: and probably check if it is defined

Comment: think globally, act in local scope!