# No database selected inside function, what the solution with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'm attempting to perform a query inside a function but it return me "No database selected". I regularly have re-initialized the PDO object inside it

```
$db = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database";
$pdo = new PDO($db, 'dbname', 'dbpassword');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
//some operations.. Works fine!

function sendMail($to)
    {
      $db = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database";
      $pdo = new PDO($db, 'dbname', 'dbpassword');
      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $qryString="SELECT Codice FROM users WHERE Mail=:mail";
      $qry = $pdo->prepare($qryString);
      $params = array("mail" => $to);
      $qry->execute($params); //won't work
    }
```

Note that operations on the DB outside the function works fine.

The problem is that the code won't work neither passing the global $pdo object.
This is the actual code

```
 $db = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database";
 $pdo = new PDO($db, 'dbname', 'dbpassword');
 $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 sendMail($mail, $pdo)

function sendMail($to, PDO $pdo)
        {
          $qryString="SELECT Codice FROM users WHERE Mail=:mail";
          $qry = $pdo->prepare($qryString);
          $params = array("mail" => $to);
          $qry->execute($params); 
        }
```

Comment: Duplicate of? [How to make PDO query work inside a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181202/how-to-make-pdo-query-work-inside-a-function)

Comment: Pass `$pdo` as a parameter of your function, or use `global $pdo;`.

Comment: alredy done that, but neither of two works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the PDO object to the function, because the scope of `$pdo` is outside the scope of `sendMail()`.

```
function sendMail(PDO $pdo, $to) {
    $queryString = "SELECT Codice FROM users WHERE Mail=:mail";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($queryString);
    $params = array("mail" => $to);
    $result = $statement->execute($params);
}
```

or

```
function sendMail($to) {
    global $pdo;
    $queryString = "SELECT Codice FROM users WHERE Mail=:mail";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($queryString);
    $params = array("mail" => $to);
    $result = $statement->execute($params);
}
```

Comment: already tryied that, but it give me the same error. Same error with both solutions

Comment: Solved, the problem was in the successive part of code that i thought to had excluded

Answer (score 3):

Variable scope has absolutely nothing to do with database connection details.
If you have a connection where database selected, the same database will be selected if you are using this connection inside a function.

So, this is a clear case of too localized question, as the problem is obviously of typo-like - connecting to wrong database, misspelling variable name, database name and such.

Unfortunately, regular PHP user has very little knowledge on performing correct, reproduceable experiment to prove their assumption. Instead, they guess the reason by indirect consequences.

You just have *to write the code you told us about* and see that database is selected all right. And then turn to search for real reason. Full error reporting (`E_ALL`) often helps a lot.

Comment: there was an error in the successive part of code that confused me about the origin of the No database selected.. I was pretty sure of have placed an exit before the code.. 
Thanks for help, now all is solved

Comment: this is why you shouldn't use tr..catch to show error message